# Checkout Form Width On Mobile

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I want to achieve this style of checkout [enter link description here](https://www.honeyglow.store/checkout/detail) where on mobile, I can get 50% width for one field (let say first name) and 50% width (last name). I have achieve this on desktop where I use `form-row-first`and`form-row-last` where i put this on my function.php.

But it seems, the field is not side-by-side. The second field just goes below the first field. I'll share my CSS for both field here, which is:

1)

```css
div.fl-wrap.fl-wrap-input #billing_first_name {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
```

2)

```css
div.fl-wrap.fl-wrap-input #billing_last_name {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
}
```

I attached the picture from my website (the problem) :[My Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H550l.jpg)
And I want to achieve like this site : [Competitor Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1fAE.jpg)

Maybe I select the wrong `div` or `label`. Anyone here can guide me? Would appreciate if anyone can contribute to this. Been 2 days since I tinkering it alone.

If you guys need to test the website, just use this test product link => [Test Product Link](https://saradesign.my/product/test-product/)

Comment: Wrap a div around the two input fields and set `display: flex` to that div

Comment: @Roy And how to achieve this? Sorry I'm not familiar on how to do this. Adding wrap to the existing field is pretty challenging for me.